# ASP.NET MVC 5 Table passing objects from View to Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm still working on my asp.net app. I have a page where orders table is displayed and i would like to include "details"column, so someone can choose order and then look up it's details.

Here is my View code:

```
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Seat</th>
            <th>Movie</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Details</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.OrderList.results)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.objectId</td>
                <td>@item.Seat</td>
                <td>LOTR</td>
                <td>@item.createdAt</td>
                <td><a href="@Url.Action("Details","Orders")">Details</a></td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Ofcourse Url.Action is just for testing. Here is my controller method:

```
 public ActionResult Details(OrderModel model)
    {

        return View(model);
    }
```

Results is a List of OrderModel objects. I'd like to pass one OrderModel object that corresponds with chosen table row. The whole point is to display OrderModel object contents on Details page. Can someone explain me how to do that?

EDIT: My model:

OrderModel

```
public class OrderModel
{
    /*class representing Order data*/
    public string Seat { get; set; }
    public string objectId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? createdAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime? updatedAt { get; set; }

}
```

My root for ordermodel(needed for json deserialization to list of objects)

```
public class OrderRootModel
{


    public List<OrderModel> results { get; set; }

}
```

My baseviewmodel orderlist line(viewmodel is shared along all sites - i'm using shared layout):

```
public OrderRootModel OrderList { get; set; }
```

**EDIT2:**
Alright so after looking at my code i modified it, so Details page recieves BaseViewModel instead of ordermodel(i'm using shared layout).

BaseViewModel:

```
public class BaseViewModel
{
    public OrderModel Order { get; set; }
    public OrderRootModel OrderList { get; set; }
}
```

OrdersController:

```
public ActionResult Details(OrderModel order)
    {
        BaseViewModel model = new BaseViewModel();
        model.Order = order;

        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: What does your model look like?

Comment: @DerekVanCuyk I've edited my post and added my model code

Comment: Why do you have to pass the complete `OrderModel`? You can pass the order Id and fetch the information form DB to show the details of order.

Comment: @user1672994 Thanks! You've enlightened me and everything works fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright guys. I think i didn't get enough sleep so my thought process was a little bit off. As @user1672994 suggested i can just pass order id to details view(if i remember right passing whole object between view and controller is not recommended).

So if anyone is interested here is a solution:

View:

```
    @foreach (var item in Model.OrderList.results)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@item.objectId</td>
        <td>@item.Seat</td>
        <td>LOTR</td>
        <td>@item.createdAt</td>
        <td><a href="@Url.Action("Details","Orders", new { id = item.objectId })">Details</a></td>
    </tr>
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Details(string id)
        {
            ApiModel data = new ApiModel();
            BaseViewModel model = new BaseViewModel();
            model.Order = data.GetOrderData(id);

            return View(model);
        }
```

Model:

```
  public OrderModel GetOrderData(string id)
{

    OrderModel model = new OrderModel();
    string url = "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Orders" + "/" + id;
    model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OrderModel>(getParseIdData(url));

    return model;

}
```

It works perfect. Thank you guys.